# Spring integration : transfer mdc in error flow

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, mdc

I'm using spring-integration

Most of my flows works on DirectChannels which assure synchronous processing of events however i've noticed that in case of any errors in these flows, the error flow is triggered on a separate thread.

My logging logic relies heavily on MDC properties and as such i'm not able to trace the errors back to the source flow.

```
@Configuration
public class GenericErrorFlow {

    public static final String CHANNEL = "errorChannel";

    @Bean
    QueueChannel errorChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel(500);
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerSpec poller() {
        return Pollers.fixedRate(500)
                .errorChannel(CHANNEL);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class ExampleFlow{

public static final String CHANNEL = "exampleFlowChannel";
  @Bean(name = CHANNEL)
    public MessageChannel getChannel() {
        DirectChannel dc = new DirectChannel();
        dc.setComponentName(CHANNEL);
        return dc;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow exampleFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(CHANNEL)
                .<ConsumerRecord>handle((message, h) -> {
                 //perform some logic here
                }).get();
    }
}
```

```
@MessagingGateway (errorChannel = GenericErrorFlow.CHANNEL)
public interface MessageGateway {
    // other routings here
}
```

Below are the few possible approaches i could think of (in order of preference):

1. We define some custom thread execution logic and transfer the MDC of the thread that runs exampleFlow to the errorFlow thread
2. We disable the async behaviour of error routing ensuring that both exampleFlow and errorFlow run on same thread. In this case there would be no need of MDC propogation
3. We serialize the MDC in some standard format and pass it along the message as one of the headers and deserialise it in the subsequent thread (this feels more of a hack; not sure if message headers were intended to be used this way)

Please suggest which of them should i go with (some entirely new approach is also fine).
Would also appreciate some pointers on how to implement approach 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `errorChannel` is decalred as a `QueueChannel`. Therefore it is pollable and processed by the scheduled tasks. Those threads in the `TaskScheduler` know nothing about the producing thread. Therefore you cannot implement your idea #1.

The second idea is the simplest and there is just enough to make your `errorChannel` as a `DirectChannel`.

The third one is fully OK and that's exactly what we do in the `ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor`. So, you just need to implement this interceptor and point to what thread state (and how) you would like to propagate from the producer to consumer over that `QueueChannel`.

NOTE: it is not OK to name your error channel as a `errorChannel` which is reserved for global default channel for errors:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/channel/special-channels.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/error-handling.html

Comment: thanks @artem.
Going with the 2nd approach.
Can you elaborate on the last point ? What issues could i run into if i have the a custom channel named `errorChannel` ? as the docs say it is okay if we want full control over the behaviour.

Comment: The `errorChannel` is the name of global channel used for error handling by default. So, imaging you have introduced a new async flow and don't specify a custom error channel over there. So, whenever exception happens in that flow, the `ErrorMessage` is going to be sent to that default global `errorChannel`. But you have a custom logic on this channel for another flow. Therefore a problem when error from a new flow is handled somehow unexpected.

Comment: The `ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor` is designed exactly for situations where we shift the work for another threads. In most cases those are scheduled threads to poll from `QueueChannel`. Therefore we don't have control over those threads from the producer and must supply context propagation some other way.